# October CMS frontend applications using database

Tags: octobercms

I'm quite new to October and played a lot with Form Builder and backend forms.
I am able to have an application with "complex queries" and business logic.

Well I thought that having the SAME on the FRONTEND side could be easy...

As backend forms are not usable in the frontend, **I would appreciate good advices** on how to develop the same for the frontend.

I understood that I should use components, but how to :
1) reuse my backend models and validation rules ?

2) create forms with equivalent forms widgets ?

3) should I use JQuery, Vue.js or something else ?

Thanks for your help, I feel quite stuck now !!!

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not for *advice* but for **technical support**. This is why you haven't received any responses.

Creating front end forms and the components to work with them are extremely easy. For most of my clients I have created a front-end admin/moderator area where they can create, edit, delete records. Only the owner of the website is given admin access to the backend and they don't need it to use it to update anything.

How you build the front-end is completely up to you, vue/react/angular is all good, I have switched to using native javascript, jquery, and OctoberCMS framework.

Your model validations should work as long as you are using the model classes to save the records. Don't update the database directly.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. So you seems to prefer JQuery for frontend ?

Comment: @Incremental Yes sir. It is a good framework and it ties directly into the OctoberCMS framework. To add, I make most of my web apps / pages not dependent on javascript to function. You don't need javascript to make a useful good looking website. But there are awesome perks to using it to make a better user experience.